# Помогите исправить код?

Tags: python

Нужно отформатировать текст, убрав пробелы, сделать первую буквы каждого слова заглавной и заменить все знаки (кроме цифр и букв) на точку

мы написали следующее:

```
def cleaner (string):
    return string.replace(' ','')
def capitalizer(string):
    return string.title()
def swapper (string):
    return string.replace('!', '.')
string = ['he!!!! huu!!']  
clean_methods = [cleaner, capitalizer, swapper]
new_string = []
for element in string:
    for function in clean_methods:
        element = function(element)
new_string.append(element)
print(new_string)
```

помогите исправить код так, чтобы он заменял не только ! и в string можно было бы записывать несколько строк

Comment: у Вас изменяет пробел и ! _____ string.replace(' ','') и string.replace('!', '.'). Создайте новую функцию и добавьте ее в clean_methods

Comment: не поможете записать ее ? просто не представляю как можно ее добавить

Comment: вам не понравилось что я написал 1 фцию вместо 3х?

Comment: for element in string:
    for function in clean_methods:
        element = function(element)
никогда больше не вызывайте функции вот так, прошу

Comment: да мне просто так понятнее, когда все подробно, я новичок в питоне и сложный синтаксис или код в одну строку чаще всего остается для меня загадкой

Comment: дзен питона звучит как простое всегда лучше сложного) если можно написать все в одной функции - пишите, в дальнейшем будет проще

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def cleaner (string):
    return string.replace(' ','')

def capitalizer(string):
    return string.title()

def swapper (string):
    new_string = string
    for s in string:
        if not s.isalnum():
            new_string = new_string.replace(s, '.')
    return new_string

string = ['he!!!! huu!!?:;\t', ' \n^he!!1!!, huu!!']  
print("было  -> ", string)
clean_methods = [cleaner, capitalizer, swapper]

new_string = []
for element in string:

    for function in clean_methods:
        element = function(element)

    new_string.append(element)

print("стало -> ", new_string)
```

---

```
было  ->  ['he!!!! huu!!?:;\t', ' \n^he!!1!!, huu!!']
стало ->  ['He....Huu......', '..He..1...Huu..']
```

---

**Update**

```
# def cleaner (string):
#     return string.replace(' ','')

def capitalizer(string):
    return string.title()

def swapper (string):
    new_string = string
    for i, s in enumerate(string):
        if not s.isalnum() and s != ' ':
            new_string = new_string.replace(s, s)   
    new_string = new_string[:i] + "." + new_string[i+1:]        

    return new_string

string = ['I am so! tired!', 'he!!!! huu!!?:;\t', ' \n^he!!1!!, huu!!']  
print("было  -> ", string)

# clean_methods = [cleaner, capitalizer, swapper]
clean_methods = [capitalizer, swapper]

new_string = []
for element in string:

    for function in clean_methods:
        element = function(element)

    new_string.append(element)

print("стало -> ", new_string)
```

---

```
было  ->  ['I am so! tired!', 'he!!!! huu!!?:;\t', ' \n^he!!1!!, huu!!']
стало ->  ['I Am So! Tired.', 'He!!!! Huu!!?:;.', ' \n^He!!1!!, Huu!.']
```

---

**Update 2**

```
def capitalizer(string):
    return string.title()

def swapper (string):
    s = ''
    for i in string[::-1]:
        if i.isalnum():
            l = len(s)
            new_string = string[:-l] + "."
            return new_string
        else:    
            s = i + s

string = ['Thank u for helping me ! :) ', 'I am so ! tired!', 'he!!!! huu!!?:;\t', ' \n^he!!1!!, huu!!']  
print("было  -> ", string)

clean_methods = [capitalizer, swapper]

new_string = []
for element in string:

    for function in clean_methods:
        element = function(element)

    new_string.append(element)

print("стало -> ", new_string)
```

---

```
было  ->  ['Thank u for helping me ! :) ', 'I am so ! tired!', 'he!!!! huu!!?:;\t', ' \n^he!!1!!, huu!!']
стало ->  ['Thank U For Helping Me.', 'I Am So ! Tired.', 'He!!!! Huu.', ' \n^He!!1!!, Huu.']
```

Comment: а как можно поменять так, чтобы питон удалял, заменял пробелы и символы только в конце
типа
было -> 'I am so! tired!'
стало -> 'I Am So! Tired.'

Comment: @СветланаШарипова посмотрите обновление.

Comment: все хорошо, только все символы в конце хорошо было бы заменить на точку
например : 'Thank u for helping me ! :) ' стало -> 'Thank You For Helping Me.'

Comment: @СветланаШарипова посмотрите обновление.2

Answer (score 2):

Вернет список, по нему легко обращаться к строкам

```py
import re

def transform(*_list):
    list_of_strings = [stroke for stroke in _list]
    total_list = []
    for string in list_of_strings:
        string = string.replace(' ', '')
        string = re.sub(r'(\W+)', r'.', string)
        string = string.title()
        total_list.append(string)
    return total_list
```